# Can't authenticate resource server using cookie JWT

Tags: cookies, asp.net-web-api, jwt

On my server I have successfully added an HTTP only cookie using

```
app.UseCookieAUthentication(...)
app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(...)
```

A user authenticates against the server at /oauth2/token which will return a Set-Cookie in the response header it does this by this call

```
context.Request.Context.Authentication.SignIn(props, identity);
```

However on the resource (client) the client is receiving the header but it is not authorized

```
 app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    AllowedAudiences = new[] { audience },
                    IssuerSecurityTokenProviders = new IIssuerSecurityTokenProvider[]
                    {
                        new SymmetricKeyIssuerSecurityTokenProvider(issuer, secret)
                    },
                    Provider = new CookieOAuthBearerProvider("authCookie")
                });

        }



public class MyAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool IsAuthorized(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        bool authenticated = actionContext.ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.IsAuthenticated;//always false!! and there are no claims...


        return base.IsAuthorized(actionContext);
    }
}
```

the `authenticated` variable is always false and has no claims what am I doing wrong??

Thanks